# Responsive not working on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, media-queries, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive website and almost done, it's ok in all browsers, browser resize screen, Android mobile but not showing better on the iPhone. Actually 90% done on the iPhone, but a banner is cut down.

Can anyone give me an idea what's wrong.

The website is: http://www.ads.eleman.ch/

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please add your css and HTML markup as well.

Comment: There are many code in it so I've shared the link on the website, you can see it from here.

Comment: Try to add `iframe{width: 100%;}` .

Comment: Already have that

Comment: I think its working fine. Please clear history and refresh the page...

Comment: Are you checked by physical iPhone or by screen resize or by tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line of code in your css:
[image]

It will fix your banner.

Here is a screenshot from an Iphone 5.

[image]

Comment: Have you iPhone and are you checked from iPhone ?

Comment: I checked on a simulated iphone. I have no way to change your source while checking on a real device.

Comment: I was removed the line please can check now ?

Comment: Looks good on Iphone 4, Iphone 5, Ipohne 6, Iphone 7 & Iphone 8. Sorry, no Iphone X but I assume it works too

Comment: Are you checked from physical device ? If yes please can you send me screenshot please ?

Comment: I added a screenshot for demonstration.

Comment: Please dont forget to mark my answer as a solution if your're happy with the result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166761/discussion-between-ab-siddik-and-tim-gerhard).